# Duplication Controls Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have such a situation here.
Let's say we have three button on our Form, and one Control, which is Panel, and which is hidden when the Form is loaded. Here is it
[image]

When I click on Button 1, that Panel have to be shown under Button1, when clicking on Button2, it have to be showned under Button2 and so on. Let's say I clicked on Button2.

[image]

Now I want that same Panel to show, when Clicking on Button1 and not at the same place. I need the same panel to be showed under buttons when clicking them.For example, the same panel is showing when clicking button 3
[image]
 I made this only working for only one button. I can't have 2 controls with same attributes, but I need somehow to duplicate that control.I  And I think it have to be done with UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void btn_click(Control sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    panel1.Left = btn.Left;
}
```

now assign this even handler to click event for all buttons.

The `var btn....` line will represent the button that was clicked, or the control that triggered the event, so from there you can set the panel's location.

Comment: But will it work if I need to show that Panel everytime under the button which was clicked. ?